# Limpar input com Jquery com mais de uma class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Meu input é assim:

```
<input type="text" class="noclear form-control" value="" name="" required>
```

Jquery:

```
form.find('input[class!="noclear"]').val('');
```

Se eu deixar o input, só com (class="noclear") funciona certinho! Mas eu preciso deixar essa outra class (form-control), pois é a formatação do input.

Pela lógica, só é para limpar os input, onde não tem a class (noclear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer selecionar todos os inputs que **não** contém a classe `noclear`, basta utilizar o seletor jQuery [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) ou o método [`jQuery.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/).

```
let $inputs = $('input:not(.noclear)');
// ou
let $inputs = $('input').not('.noclear');
```

Exemplo:

```js
$('#clear-button').on('click', function() {
    $('input').not('.noclear').val('');
});
```

```css
.form-control {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="form-control noclear" value="noclear">
<input class="form-control" value="Input 2">
<input class="form-control" value="Input 3">
<input class="form-control" value="Input 4">

<button id="clear-button">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Testei sua solução, mas mesmo assim está limpando o campo :(

Comment: Então está faltando informação na sua pergunta. Pois a solução funciona

Comment: Era o maldito cache kkkkkk. Funcionou agora! kkkkkkk. Muito obrigado! Aqui eu testei também: ( form.find('input').not(".noclear").val(''); ) e retornou certinho, igual sua solução. Parece que tem várias maneiras para fazer isso, gostei.

Answer (score 0):

faz assim que é bem mais simples:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.meubotaolimpa').click(function(e) {
        $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').not('.noclear').each(function() {
                $(this).val('');
        });
    });
});
```

`.meubotaolimpa` é a classe do botão ( serve só como ex )

editado

Comment: O autor da pergunta quer fazer o contrário, limpar todos os inputs **exceto** os que têm a classe `noclear`.

Comment: Só uma dica, o `$.val()` já usa o `$.each()` internamente, então não precisa usar os dois, bastaria fazer `$('.noclear').val('')` que funcionaria igual. :D