# Como limpar vários campos input pelas classes?

Tags: input

Como limpar o valor de vários campos input pelas classes? Utilizando Jquery?

Fiz assim, mas não fucionou!

```js
form.find('input').not(".class1 .class2 .class3").val('');
```

Comment: Preencha as tags corretamente, qual linguagem está usando? Javascript puro? JQuery?

Comment: Como está seu formulário? cite exemplos

Comment: Talvez seja duplicada de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/341638/6333, que você mesmo é o autor.

Comment: Porque você está fazendo a mesma pergunta?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Limpar input com Jquery com mais de uma class](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/341638/limpar-input-com-jquery-com-mais-de-uma-class)

Answer (score -3):

Minha sugestão é adicionar uma classe em comum em todos os inputs que quer limpar e usar essa classe, caso haja inputs com mais de uma classe. Por exemplo, supondo que tenha 3 tipos de classes - cls1, cls2 e cls3. Adicione uma classe em comum a todos, como no exemplo abaixo:

```js
$("#btn-reset").click(function(){
    $(".cls-comum").val("");
});
```

```css
input{
    margin: 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="cls1 cls-comum" value="Nome" /><br />
<input type="text" class="cls1 cls-comum" value="Sobrenome" /><br />
<input type="text" class="cls2 cls-comum" value="Idade" /><br />
<input type="text" class="cls3 cls-comum" value="Endereço" /><br />
<input type="submit" class="cls4" value="ENVIAR" />
<input type="button" class="cls4" id="btn-reset" value="LIMPAR" />
```